# drawing mutliple images in one line

Tags: javascript, image

How would i simplify this, so it has the same effect?

```
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y2,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y3,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y4,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y5,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y6,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y7,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y8,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y9,tileWidth,tileHeight);
```

I have "imgs2" saved like this, in an array

```
function images2(callback){
    for(var i = 0; i<enemy2.length; i++){
        var tile4 = new Image();
        imgs2.push(tile4);

        tile4.onload = function(){
            imagesdraw=true; 
            if (imagesdraw == true) {
                callback();
            }
        }
        tile4.src = enemy2[i];
    }
}
```

so how would I make the `drawImage` simpler, so it doesn't look so drawn out, so that it is just one line that can work for multiple images alongside the different y's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking advantage of being able to access properties via `obj.["propertyToGet"]`, you can simplify this:

```
ontext.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y2,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y3,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y4,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y5,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y6,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y7,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y8,tileWidth,tileHeight);
context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy.y9,tileWidth,tileHeight);
```

into this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
  var propertyName = "";
  if(i > 1){
    propertyName = "y" + i;
  }
  context.drawImage(imgs2[0],enemy.x+135,enemy[propertyName], tileWidth, tileHeight);
}
```

It just seems cleaner.